# How to write a function for position sizing for investment portfolio

Tags: r, portfolio, quantitative-finance, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to write a function that applies position-sizing analysis for a portfolio of assets and I'm stuck on some basic coding in R. The basic set-up for one asset to determine the % allocation for the portfolio is a simple ratio:

**fixed risk % for asset / asset's volatility**

It's tricky with multiple assets because the total allocation % can't exceed 100%. Here's what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to finesse the code so that it makes sense in a total portfolio context. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
# start by downloading 2 assets
library(tseries)
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

symbols = c("SPY","AGG")
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo', from='2003-12-31')
spy <-Ad(SPY)
agg <-Ad(AGG)

# calculate daily % return and rolling 100-day volatility (std dev)
spy.ret <-na.omit(ROC(spy,1,"discrete"))
agg.ret <-na.omit(ROC(agg,1,"discrete"))

# calculate annualized volatility 
spy.sd <-na.omit(rollapplyr(spy.ret,100,sd))*sqrt(252)
agg.sd <-na.omit(rollapplyr(agg.ret,100,sd))*sqrt(252)

# calculate position size (as %) for each asset with fixed 2% risk factor
# to determine fraction of the account size
spy.pos.size <-.02/spy.sd
agg.pos.size <-.02/agg.sd

# combine position size data and
# sum for aggregate portfolio allocation
spy.agg.pos.size <-cbind(spy.pos.size,agg.pos.size)
port.pos.size <-apply(spy.agg.pos.size,1,sum)
```

Check the max allocation total: shows that the % exceeds 100% (i.e., 1.0)

```
> max(port.pos.size)
[1] 1.131178
```

Any recommendations on how to keep total allocation at/below 100% while retaining the allocation recommendations in the individual position size calculations for each asset? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Can you clarify on the sizing rule? e.g. w/sigma? and then rescale weights to 1?

Comment: As one possibility, let's say there's a max weight of 50% for each asset in this case. To the extent that the total weights are less than 100%, the remainder is in cash: SHV, for instance. The weights are calculated on a rolling basis, as per the spy.pos.size and agg.pos.size data.